# Invalid Syntax near Begin

Tags: sql, syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertSummary

    (
    @symbol nvarchar(50),
    @openValue nvarchar(50),
    @closeValue nvarchar(50),
    @highvalue nvarchar(50),
    @lowvalue varchar(50),
    @currentValue nvarchar(50),
    @change nvarchar(50),
    @volume nvarchar(50)
    )

BEGIN

INSERT INTO [MarketSummary]
     (
        [Symbol],
        [Open],
        [Close],
        [High],
        [Low],
        [Current],
        [Change],
        [Volume]
    ) VALUES 
    ( 
        @symbol,
        @openValue,
        @closeValue,
        @highValue,
        @lowValue,
        @currentValue,
        @change,
        @volume
)
;

END
```

Comment: What database language is that supposed to be? What is the error message?

Comment: Please don't downvote a question without commenting on why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you review the [syntax of `CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) you will see that it requires `AS` before the `BEGIN`.